# JavaScript multiple input validations

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to validate  Surname required field and NIC should only be in Numbers. But the problem is this code not checking NIC.

```
<script>
  function validateform(SnameAddress,mail,NIC,dob){
    var required=""
    if(document.getElementById("Sname").value == ""){
      alert("Surname : field is required");
      return false;
    }
  }

  function validateNIC(NIC){
    var nic=document.getElementById("NIC").value;
    if(isNaN(nic)){
      alert("NIC : incorrect NIC num"); 
      return false;
    }
  }

</script>

<form action="MAILTO:info@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="#"
onsubmit="return (validateform() && validateNIC())">

  Surname <input type="text" id="Sname" >
  NIC <input type="text" id="NIC">
</form>
```

Comment: Why won't you set `type="number"` to *NIC* field ?

Comment: The value from an input will always be a string, you could try `isNaN(Number(nic))`

Comment: You call `validateform()` without param, and you define the function with param...Same as `validateNIC()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logical AND operation '&&' employs short-circuiting behavior which means that if the first condition didn't return true, It will not check the second condition.
So we have two conditions here:

- `validateform()` returns false if `Sname.value` is equal "", then the AND operation will not check for the seocnd condtion and will not enter `validateNIC()` function.
- `validateform()` will not return true if `Sname.value` is not equal "", then also the AND operation will not check for the seocnd condtion

So you can add `return ture;` at the end of `validateform()` but this will make you only enter `validateNIC()` if `Sname.value` is not equal ""

If you want to check both you can put all the validation in the same function like that:

```
<script>
  function validateform() {
    var isValid = true;
    if (document.getElementById("Sname").value == "") {
      alert("Surname : field is required");
      isValid = false;
    }
    var nic = document.getElementById("NIC").value;
    if (isNaN(nic)) {
      alert("NIC : incorrect NIC num");
      isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
  }
</script>
<form action="MAILTO:info@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="#" onsubmit="return validateform()">
  Surname
  <input type="text" id="Sname"> NIC
  <input type="text" id="NIC">
</form>
```

Comment: after i change the functions, the problem is now its only checks the validateForm() and whether it's true or false, its calling to the form method

Comment: I added a code that will check for all conditions whatever happens

Answer (score 2):

I can suppose that you didn't check isNaN function well. For example:

```
isNaN("123.0")
false
isNaN("123,0")
true
```

So try to play with isNaN build-in function via developers console (f12) to check your possible inputs. Maybe you need to write some logic above existing code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because you don't return true on `validateform` if it is valid. Because of that, in "and" (&&) condition there is no reason to check the second part of the condition when the first part is not true, so validateNIC is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: If you don't use param in your function, juste remove it.
`function validateform(SnameAddress,mail,NIC,dob)` -> `function validateform()`

`function validateNIC(NIC)` -> `function validateNIC()`

Step 2 : Add return true (As said @Dmitry Surin)

```
function validateform(){
   var required=""
   if(document.getElementById("Sname").value == ""){
       console.log("Surname : field is required");
       return false;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}

function validateNIC(){
   var nic=document.getElementById("NIC").value;
   if(isNaN(nic)){
      console.log("NIC : incorrect NIC num"); 
      return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/431790/

Comment: is there any problem with the way that I calling onsubmit event?

Comment: no, this is right, i just modify for the jsfiddle result, so we can see the result of validateform() && validateNIC()

Comment: even though i followed your code, it's not checking  Nic is Numeric or not